# procrastination vs. procrastinating?

Tags: word-choice

Out of these two sentences, which one is correct?

> The mouse indicated persistent annoyances likely to be caused by my procrastination tendencies.

or

> The mouse indicated persistent annoyances and irritations, likely to be caused by my procrastinating tendencies.

Comment: Basically, shall I use: procrastination tendencies or procrastinating tendencies?  does it matter ?

Comment: When in doubt, simply use a natural way of saying things, like "caused by my tendency to procrastinate"

Comment: What does the mouse have to do with it?  I'm not sure I understand the meaning of your sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Your first sentence might be reformatted to use the *noun* as

> The mouse indicated persistent annoyances likely to be caused by my procrastination.
>   The mouse indicated persistent annoyances likely to be caused by my *tendency for* procrastination.

Your second sentence is correct and understandable using the *adjective*

> The mouse indicated persistent annoyances and irritations, likely <s>to be</s> caused by my procrastinating tendencies.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would restructure the sentence to say "tendency to procrastinate". It feels much more natural as a native speaker.

Edit* sorry, I didn't realise I just stole a comment from the original post.

You could also use "procrastinatory/procrastinative tendencies", making it an adjective describing your tendencies.